# libgit2: git checkout <hash>

Tags: c, git, libgit2

How to make similar on `git checkout hash` via libgit2? I was trying as below:

```
git_checkout_options opts;
opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE | GIT_CHECKOUT_REMOVE_UNTRACKED;
opts.paths.strings = "*";
opts.paths.count = 1;
...
git_checkout_tree(repo, (const git_object *) commit, &opts);
...
```

It has no effect. Files in repo stay in final state.

Comment: How did you get the variable `commit` based on the hash?

Comment: @YoichiNakayama I created `git_revwalk *walker;` and look over with `git_revwalk_next` until found required oid. To get commit I used `git_commit_lookup`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 
Let's check the other points with assumtion that the commit is specified correctly.
(1) What is the return value of git_checkout_tree ?
(2) Does giving NULL instead of &opts change the return value and behavior?
(3) As described in checkout.h, opts should be initialized with GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT. Does doing that change the return value and behavior?

Comment: @YoichiNakayama I had to initialize `opts` structure with `GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Initialize opts structure with GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT as:

```
git_checkout_options opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
```

Reason: A struct in libgit2 like git_checkout_options has a member variable `unsigned int version` for a validation.
Uninitialized struct causes error on the validation with the macro GIT_ERROR_CHECK_VERSION which is called inside of git_checkout_tree().